# How to translate date-time for multi local in ionic 2 with ng2-translate?

Tags: angular, ionic2, ng2-translate

I want to translate ionic date-time. That's why I'm using **ng2-translate** package.

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="DDDD MMM D, YYYY" [(ngModel)]="myDate" monthNames="janeiro, fevereiro, march, ..." ></ion-datetime>
```

here,  I'm using `monthNames="{{ 'MONTHS' | translate }}" or [monthNames]="'MONTHS' | translate"` as translation rules of **ng2-translate** but its not work just showing an error Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

If there are any other solution please answer.

Comment: Is `MONTHS` a *variable*? If so, It should be `monthNames="{{ MONTHS | translate }}" or [monthNames]="MONTHS | translate"`.

Comment: no translation key which is define in translation .json file  {{ 'MONTHS' | translate }} is define as rules.. **'MONTHS'** with single coat quote.